# Delta lake merge doesn't update schema (automatic schema evolution enabled)

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I get an error when I execute the following line of code:

```
deltaTarget.alias('target').merge(df.alias('source'), mergeStatement).whenMatchedUpdateAll().whenNotMatchedInsertAll().execute()
```

The error is the following:

AnalysisException: cannot resolve new_column in UPDATE clause given columns {List of target columns}. The 'new_column' is indeed not in the schema of the target delta table, but according to the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#merge-schema-evolution&language-python), this should just update the existing schema of the delta table and add the column.

I also enable the autoMerge with this command:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled ","true")
```

I am not sure what exactly causes this error because in the past I was able to evolve the schema of delta tables automatically with these exact pieces of code.

Is there something that I am overlooking?

Comment: Can you please share what databricks runtime are you using ?

Comment: In my case this turned to be a wrong error message hiding the real issue. (and yes, it's a bug to display the wrong error message) - which was mismatching types between two fields I tried to join on in the merge into command

Answer (score 5):

you have to remove the space after `..autoMerge.enabled` in the `spark.conf.set`

--> it's

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled","true")
```

, **not**

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled ","true")`
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with you, but i find that in delta lake [docs](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#schema-validation), it may not likely support the part columns with upsertAll() and insertAll();
So i choose the upsertExpr() and insertExpr() with a big map contains all the columns.

[delta lake merge : Schema validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2QCL.png)

Comment: Can you give an example to replace 'whenMatchedUpdateAll()' and 'whenNotMatchedInsertAll' in 'updateExpr()' and 'insertExpr()'.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you need to use the insertAll or updateAll options on the MERGE operation

Comment: But the op specified that this he uses updateAll/insertAll (in the format of whenMatchedInsertAll etc

Answer (score 0):

spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled","true")

Ensure there is no space after "enabled" in above line.

then you can use pass a spark sql:

```
spark.sql(f"""
MERGE INTO {data_path} delta USING global_temp.src source
       ON   delta.col1   =    source.key1
       AND  delta.col2   =    source.key2
      
       WHEN MATCHED THEN
         UPDATE SET *
         
       WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
         INSERT *
""")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
deltaTable.as("target")
.merge(data.as("source"),
  "source.internalUUID = target.internalUUID")
.whenMatched().updateAll()
.whenNotMatched().insertAll()
.execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**